# How to generate caption from img alt atribute

Tags: emacs, org-mode, pandoc

Is there a way to convert an `img` tag containing an `alt` attribute (in a html file),

```
<img src="pics/01.png" alt="my very first pic"/>
```

to an image link plus caption (org file),

```
#+CAPTION: my very first pic
[[pics/01.png]]
```

using [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/)?

I'm calling `pandoc` like this:

```
$ pandoc -s -r html index.html -o index.org
```

where `index.html` contains the `img` tag from above, but it doesn't add the caption in the output org file:

```
[[pics/01.png]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently the [Org Writer unfortunately throws away the image `alt` and `title` strings](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/master/src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/Org.hs#L297). Feel free to submit an issue or patch if there's a way to do `alt` text in Org.

You can also always write a [filter](http://pandoc.org/scripting.html) to modify the doc AST and add the alt text to an additional paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

OP here. I didn't manage to make pandoc bend to my needs in this case. But a little bash scripting with some awk help does the trick.
The script replaces all img tags with org-mode equivalents plus captions. Pandoc leaves these alone when converting from html to org-mode.

The awk script,

```
# replace_img.awk
#
# Sample input:
#   <img src="/pics/01.png" alt="my very first pic"/>
# Sample output:
#   #+CAPTION: my very first pic
#   [[/pics/01.png]]

BEGIN {
    # Split the input at "
    FS = "\""
}
# Replace all img tags with an org-mode equivalent.
/^<img src/{
    print "#+CAPTION: " $4
    print "[["$2"]]"
}
# Leave the rest of the file intact.
!/^<img src/
```

and the bash script,

```
# replace_img.sh

php_files=`find -name "*.php"`
for file in $php_files; do
    awk -f replace_img.awk $file > tmp && mv tmp $file
done
```

Place these files at the root of the project, `chomod +x replace_img.sh` and then run the script: `./replace_img.sh`. Change the extension of the files, if needed. I've had over 300 php files.